Gremlin: filter for existence of a path to the current node in a traversal
I'm looking for how to filter for the existence of a path to the current node in a traversal. In particular, I'm trying to sort two user's activities first by in common, and second by number of places they have selected for the given activity. The second criterion is the one I am unsure of how to implement.
   let query = this.g
      .V(userId)
      .union(this.g.V(friend.id))
      .values('user')
      .out('IS_INTERESTED_IN')
      .hasLabel('activity')
      .as('activity')
      .order()
      .by(__.count())
      .by(
        __.select('user')
          .out('IS_INTERESTED_IN')
          .hasLabel('place')
          // NOTE: QUESTION ABOUT THIS LINE
          .where(__.out('IS_PLACE_FOR').is(__.select('activity').identity()))
          .count(),
      )
      .dedup()
      .toList();

I could write the below, but navigating Activity -> Places -> User instead of User -> Places -> Activity is a much more expensive operation, as the expected degree in the first case is much higher. This is why I'm attempting it as written above.
...
  // NOTE: QUESTION ABOUT THIS LINE
  .where(__.in_('IS_PLACE_FOR').in_('IS_INTERESTED_IN').or(__.hasId(userId), __.hasId(friendId)))

My key point of confusion is how to have a subtraversal compare equality to a node from earlier in the traversal.
I made this simple experiment which suggests my current approach will fail. I would expect the two queries to return the same value.
> await gr.V(tim).as('tim').out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').is(__.select('tim').identity()).count().next()
{ value: 0, done: false }
> await gr.V(tim).as('tim').out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').hasId(tim).count().next()
{ value: 249, done: false }

Am I thinking about this correctly? If so, how do I express what I'm trying to achieve?
